# Android configuration problem in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I enter the site below

> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

in `Install new software` window it finds the Android Developer Tools.

When I check all and hit install it shows the error below and the ADT is not getting installed.

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/[3.4.0.I20080610-1200,3.4.0.I20080610-1200]] can be satisfied.
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/[3.4.0.v20080512,3.4.0.v20080512]] can be satisfied.
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/[3.4.0.I20080610-1200,3.4.0.I20080610-1200]] can be satisfied.
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/[3.4.0.v20080512,3.4.0.v20080512]] can be satisfied.
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.5.0
Unsatisfied dependency: [com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.ui/3.5.0
```

What causes this? How can I solve the issue?

Comment: try using http instead of https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites, do you have other sites available other than `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` like:

- `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios`
- `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6`

If not, add them and test that.

And check if case "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" in "Install software" is checked please

Comment: I am having the same issue as the above person. For me at least, this answer does not work. (just a heads up for others)

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. And got the solution.

My ADT was demanding me any ecplise above or 3.5. And I was trying in 3.4 base version.

Used 3.5 and it worked brilliantly..

And I can see your log details giving the same kind of error.

Please update your eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There are some missing prerequisities, like

Cannot find a solution where both **Match[requiredCapability**:

Try download [ADT-10.0.1.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-10.0.1.zip) and Install as archive in Eclipse
Instruction can be found at [Installing the ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Eclipse might be jacked up. Have you tried a fresh download of the latest version?